# How to create custom page and URL run time?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I create a page in WordPress. This is my page url

```
www.example.com/test
```

When i hit this URL its working fine. This page has some links that did not have any page like this.

```
www.example.com/test/calculate
```

When i hit on this URL it give 404. I know this page is not exist and also i don't want to create it. Also i don't want to edit 404 template to display. I want that this custom page should look real.

So how to achieve this?

Comment: In HTML you could do `<a href="#">`, linking back to `www.example.com/test#`, which is a no-operation. I don't have experience with WordPress but I suppose it should be possible to change the links for the mock version just like that.

Comment: I know this solution but i also want SEO friendly URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `.htaccess` with `RewriteRule`. Fot example:

```
   RewriteRule /test/(.*) /test/
```

But it depends where you want to inner redirect that urls to.

Answer (score 0):

404 page is Error page, Which called when anything not found in your website.

1)) For Editing 404 page Some theme provide option for that. So, first check your theme options any option related to 404 page?.

2)) You can also use this plugin for customize $404 page :[404page plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404page/)

3)) To edit your Theme’s 404 error template file:

- --Open your WordPress admin panel:
- --Choose Appearance menu.
- --Choose the Theme Editor page.
- --Check to see if your theme includes a ‘404 Template’ in the list of files.
- --Click the link for ‘404 Template’ along the right side of the page.
- --Edit the message text to say what you want it to say.
- --Save your changes.

The default 404.php file will look like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
   <div id="content">
     <h2>Error 404 - Not Found</h2>
   </div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```